# Linking Data from two google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am wanting to link data from my google sheet that tracks peoples vacation. I have another sheet that I will then use to print out for people to easily see who is off. Can anyone help me with the logic to get the data from a range of cells and only return the name of the person?

I can't share the sheets because there bound to my company and I can't share outside of the company. I can share screen shot of what it is I am trying to get done. Any ideas that would make this easier would be helpful. Also I tried to link the tracker to Google Calendar, where I made a new one

[CalendarChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxxvT.png) [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DqDh.png)
[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfW5x.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: "I can't share the sheets because they are bound to my company and I can't share outside of the company." Yes, I do understand and many people have the same problem. But it is important to share a copy of your spreadsheet and there is a workaround. Remove the private and confidential data and replace it with dummy data; then share a copy of that spreadsheet.

Comment: you can share sample sheet, I mean sample data sheet

Comment: Still struggling to get this to work . I have made some improvements but still can't get the function I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a custom function that retrieves a list of names for each day based on vacation input.

## [Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sjdnO7Hs9Hp8ruT3jE-9vkivZ0oups_tVadzqPa40Lo/edit?usp=sharing)

## How it works:

Based on the Input sheet, the formula finds the column with the correct date, then looks at that column for any `v`  characters, if it finds any, it will add the name to the results.

## Considerations

The day numbers are date objects formatted to show only the date of the month.
The Month names are showing the Month of the date below them. (just cosmetic)
If instead of just looking for `v` you want to look for anything (`h`,`p`, etc) you can change the commented line to `!=""`. However, more adaptation will be needed to return a list that differentiates between vacations and half-days, for example.

## Code

```
function test(){
  GETVACATIONS(new Date("2019-01-02"));
}

function GETVACATIONS(date) {
  const inputSheetName = "Input";
  const namesColumns = 1;
  const dateRow = 2;
  const dateStartCol = 8;
  
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var inputSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(inputSheetName);
  var nameSize = inputSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow()-dateRow;
  
  date = date.setHours(1,0,0,0); //reset time for uniform search
  
  var result = [];
  
  //Find cell that has the correct date.
  var lookupDateRange = inputSheet.getRange(dateRow, dateStartCol, 1, inputSheet.getMaxColumns()-dateStartCol);
  var foundIndex = lookupDateRange.getValues()[0].map(function (x) {return x.setHours(1,0,0,0);}).indexOf(date);
  if (foundIndex!=-1) {
    //match found
    var lookupColumn = dateStartCol+foundIndex;
    var lookupDataRange = inputSheet.getRange(dateRow+1, lookupColumn, nameSize);
    //Collect rows that have data, fetch the usernames on that row.
    for (var r=0; r<lookupDataRange.getValues().length; r++) {
      if (lookupDataRange.getValues()[r][0]==="v") {//Has vacation. Might change to if !="" if you want to register any non empty
        result.push(inputSheet.getRange(dateRow+1+r, namesColumns).getValue());
      }
    }
  }
  return result.sort().toString();
}
```

## Usage

Add to a cell the formula `=GETVACATIONS(date)` where date is a `Date` object or a reference to a cell with one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201533/discussion-on-answer-by-zektorh-linking-data-from-two-google-sheets).